# Flink Task Executor shutting down

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

Flink does not clean task manager heap and after a few flink job run. Task Executor shutting down exception is occurring.

How to clean or restart flink task manager?

Comment: What version of Flink is this? What have you looked at to diagnose the problem? How do you know the heap is holding onto data? This shouldn't happen, but in some older versions of Flink there were classloader issues that could cause this.

Comment: It is 12 version and I checked direct memory usages, all libraries are set to provided. I am using Global windows. When there is no job run also memory usage increasiing.

Comment: It is possible to create an unbounded amount of state with global windows. Would need (a lot) more info to see if that's really the problem. As for your original question, switching to per-job clusters would be one way to get a clean TM for each run.

Comment: How can I force to clean the windows data or restart/clean task peridically, I searched a lot but could not find a solution

Comment: You can use state TTL to force data clean-up.